# How to identify "Alt +" keypress, properly and reliably?

Tags: java, keyboard, awt

My question is actually more general, but I'm using the action of a user holding down the "Alt" key, and pressing "+", as an example that shows the difficulties.

I'm working an a US English keyboard, which has the "=" (lowercase) and "+" (uppercase) on the same key, so to press "Alt +" (as might be indicated in a menu entry), I have to actually press "Alt Shift =".  In Java AWT, pressing "Alt Shift =" generates a key-pressed KeyEvent with the keycode associated with the "=" key, and a key-typed KeyEvent containing the "±" character. So there is no obvious, reliable way of programatically deciding that "Alt" was held down while the "+" key was pressed.

I could do some mapping internally to fix this, such as mapping "±" to "Alt +", or mapping "Shift {keycode for = }" to "+".  However, there don't seem to be any guarantees that this would work across different keyboard layouts; and it certainly isn't good coding style.

If anyone can suggest a way around these problems, or perhaps point be to code that's already handled this difficulty, I'd be most appreciative.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to decide if want to know which keys have been pressed or which  keys have been typed. Normally you should detect key typed, as the key pressed for a key typed change across different keyboards, and normally you need to know when the key is typed (key pressed and released), not just when is pressed and the user can hold the key for a while.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the reply. I agree that monitoring "keyTyped" would be best, but like I say, that doesn't identify the actual character the user sees on the keyboard, which is what I want to be able to do.<br>In addition, handling something like "Alt-e" is problematic, as that doesn't invoked keyTyped on a keypress, and monitoring presses of "Alt-e Alt-<some other character>" is really painful via keyTyped is really painful, as that can produce accented characters.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if(e.isAltDown())
{
    switch(e.getKeyChar())
    {
        case '+':
            System.out.println("Plus");
        break;
    }
}
```

**Where** `e` is the `KeyEvent` and it is handled in `keyPressed` method.

The above code will print **Plus** when you press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> on the keyboard specified by you.

For complete working code see the below example:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;


public class SwingTest 
{

    private static JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        frame = new JFrame("Event Test");

        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();  
        int xSize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth()/2) + 100;  
        int ySize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight()/2) + 50;  

        frame.setSize(xSize,ySize); 
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() 
        {
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
            {
                if(e.isAltDown())
                {
                    switch(e.getKeyChar())
                    {
                    case '+':
                        System.out.println("Plus");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });         
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi Favonius,thanks for the detailed answer. However, this didn't work on my system (OS X 10.6, Java 6 most recent update on OS X), so I modified the code to get rid of the switch and simply do                
                    "System.out.println(e.getKeyChar());" As had been the case with my Scala code, the character that is printed out is "±" (that's a small + immediately above a small -; the "plus or minus" mathematical symbol). Sigh.

Comment: @Kenneth McDonald: The demo was written on a Win Vista machine with Java 1.6_b18 (not the current version). Not sure about `OS X`. Will dig on it for some more time.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it; There's probably a keyboard mapping layer added by Apple that I would have to dig into, and in any case, this is not a show-stopper for me. I'm sort of expecting that JavaFX 2 is going to end up being the actual UI kit I target, so using AWT is just a stopgap until JFX 2 goes public. I really appreciate your time, but no reason for you to take even more time on something that won't benefit you.